# Tuples in Python

Tags: python

> Write a procedure called `oddTuples`, which takes a tuple as input, and returns a new tuple as output, where every other element of the input tuple is copied, starting with the first one. So if test is the tuple `('I', 'am', 'a', 'test', 'tuple')`, then evaluating `oddTuples` on this input would return the tuple `('I', 'a', 'tuple')`.

My code:

```
def oddTuples(aTup):

    nT = ()

    for i in aTup:
        if (i+1) % 2 != 0:
            nT = nT + (i,)
    return nT
```

My output:

```
TypeError: oddTuples() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: How do you call the `oddTuples` function?

Comment: why don't you return `aTup[::2]` directly?

Comment: You both are complete right, the point for me not to slice just for practice since I am complete new using Python. Thank you !!!!111

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely doing this:

```
oddTuples('I', 'am', 'a', 'test', 'tuple')
```

What you need to do is:

```
oddTuples(('I', 'am', 'a', 'test', 'tuple'))
```

In the 1st scenario, what you're *actually* doing is passing 5 separate strings, in other words 5 arguments. What you want is to enclose them with an additional parentheses on both sides to indicate a tuple. You seem to have confused the parentheses syntax associated with ***function calling*** for that of the `tuple`'s. Easy to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I presume the problem is how you pass argument to a oddTuple().

```
def oddTuples(atup):
    print(atup)

oddTuples(1, 2, 3)
# TypeError: oddTuples() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

-- this passes three arguments to oddTuples, each of type int

To make aTup a tuple, do it explicitly:

```
def oddTuples(atup):
    print(atup)

oddTuples((1, 2, 3))
# (1, 2, 3)
```

Or use variable arguments syntax:

```
# `*atup` means: "The caller may pass any number of non-keyword 
# arguments. Make them available inside the function by collecting
# them all in a tuple named `atup`."
def oddTuples(*atup):
    print(atup)

oddTuples(1, 2, 3)
# (1, 2, 3)
```

---

Also, logic inside oddTuples is incorrect. for X in SEQ will iterate over elements ('I', 'am', ...) not their indexes. To add indexes to iteration use enumerate():

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    nT = ()
    for i, a in enumerate(aTup):
        if (i + 1) % 2 != 0:
            nT = nT + (a,)
    return nT
```

Comment: Thank you to every one ! I see now the problem

Comment: Now I get the problem that if the Tuple is filled with numbers then ... is adding them ... mistake one so, how can I fix .. this code to actually just create a new Tuple using the oods of the original tuple ... ex... ('I', 'have', 2, 'medals', 'and', 1 'toy') output should be ...('I','have', ,'medals', 1 ) my code

def oddTuples((aTup)):


    nT = ()
    for i in range (len(aTup)):
        if (i+1) % 2 != 0:
            nT = nT + (aTup[i],)
        return nT

my output 
oddTuples(x)
 ('I',)

Comment: Hmm, I think output should be: `('I', 2, 'and', 'toy')`

Answer (score 1):

Here's simple use of `range()` and `iteration` to solve the problem:

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    '''
    aTup: a tuple

    returns: tuple, every other element of aTup.
    '''
    oddTup = ()
    for i in range(len(aTup)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            oddTup = oddTup + (aTup[i],)
    return oddTup

print(oddTuples((4, 0, 7, 20, 4, 1, 0, 16)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make this code very simple. Look at exactly what it is asking. You just need to return a value for every other element in that tuple.

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
   t = aTup[0: :2]
   return t
```

Answer (score 0):

def oddTuples(aTup):
    return aTup[::2]